# PHP configure Windows Task Scheduler from PHP

Tags: php, yii2, scheduled-tasks

Currently I'm using Windows Task Scheduler to run (every day at 8:00) a Yii2 php script.

Is there any way to change the task's start time **from php** (my client wants to set the task's time from an admin site dinamically)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, MSDN has an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383665(VS.85).aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-wl7B4rIU_J1DETcA.3k5mw&tduid=(6384fc278458aaa6c95beb03bb294d9a)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-wl7B4rIU_J1DETcA.3k5mw)()) of adding a task to run at a certain time.  Also, the example has given us an outline of the steps to accomplish this:

- Create a TaskService Object and Get a task folder
- Create a task (with TaskService.NewTask)
- Define information about the task
- Create a time-based trigger
- Create an action for the task
- Register the task

So for starting it in php to create a task you should do something like this

```
//Create service object
$serviceObj= new COM("Schedule.Service");
$serviceObj->Connect();
$taskFolder = $serviceObj->GetFolder("\\");

//create the task
$oTaskDefinition = $serviceObj->NewTask(0);

//add task description
$RegistrationInfo = $oTaskDefinition->RegistrationInfo;
$RegistrationInfo->Description = "Start notepad";
$RegistrationInfo->Author = "Author Name";
```

You can see this [article](https://codesnob.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/creating-windows-task-with-php/) which can guide you along to complete all the above steps using `php` and trigger the tasks at times

Comment: Thank you, It looks promising!